# Android: Dynamically replacing fragments on a custom layout

Tags: android, layout, fragment

I am trying to programatically add fragments to an activity with a custom layout, as I want to change them on button clicks.

I read the tutorials and managed to add them when the activity has a LinearLayout. However, when I use mine the fragment does not show up.

It is probably that it is not begin laid out, but I do not know how to do this. I am laying out the FrameLayout where I want to put them, but I do not know where the fragments have to be laid out. Here is the code (I want to display a BlogFragment where the FrameLayout is placed):

main_activity.xml

```
<com.example.myfirstapp.MainLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_window"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<fragment android:name = "com.example.myfirstapp.ButtonsFragment"
    android:id = "@+id/buttons"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<fragment android:name = "com.example.myfirstapp.SignatureFragment"
    android:id = "@+id/signature"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:background="@color/orange"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/central_window"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00FF00"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

</com.example.myfirstapp.MainLayout>
```

MainLayout.java

```
public class MainLayout extends ViewGroup {

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    final int w = r-l;
    final int h = b-t;
    getChildAt(0).layout(0, 0, w, 30);
    getChildAt(1).layout(0, h-20, w, h);
    getChildAt(2).layout(0, 30, w, h-20);
}
/*
*   Constructors
*/
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    BlogFragment blogFragment = new BlogFragment();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.central_window, blogFragment);
    ft.commit();
}
```

Comment: Are you using `Support Library` or not?

Comment: @Xchihnegn No, I am calling android.app.Fragment. Does it make any difference?

Comment: So your `MainActivity` is extends `Activity`?

Comment: i am not sure yoour mainlayout, you could test with linearlayout

Comment: @Xchihnegn As I mentioned before, when using a linerlayout the code with fragments works. I want to keep the custom layout because I will further implement more complex laying out, and I want to avoid chaining LinearLayouts.

I think the problem is that the fragments are being placed as children of the FrameLayout element and the are not getting laid out for some reason. But I can not figure out the problem.